# iOS Push notifications stop working after to add Firebase SDK

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using push notifications in my project with APNS.
The push notifications worked well before to add and config Firebase SDK.
I noticed that after to add Firebase the function: `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is not called.

I don't know if there is something that I have to disable in Firebase, if I remove the Firebase set up (FirebaseApp.configure()) the function`didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is called again.

My code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // ... existing code ...
    registerForPushNotifications()
    return true
}

func registerForPushNotifications() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
        (granted, error) in
        print("Permission granted: \(granted)")

        guard granted else { return }
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data -> String in
        return String(format: "%02.2hhx", data)
    }

    let token = tokenParts.joined()
    print("Device Token: \(token)")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Failed to register: \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just turn off method swizzling in FCM: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in